# Sorting by Date from Inputbox - VBA

Tags: excel, sorting, date, vba

I am having a tough time figuring out why I can't get this code to sort by date. I have it so that the way the date is typed is in the same format as the dates in the log, I've double checked that it's searching the correct column... I'm just coming up with a blank here.

```
Sub Sortbydate()

With ActiveSheet
Dim When As Variant
Dim noreallywhen As String

When = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT: MM-DD-YY")
Range("C16").Value = When

noreallywhen = Sheets("FIND RECORDS").Range("D16").Value

Worksheets("Log").Activate
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$D$1:$D$1000").AutoFilter Field:=1, 
Criteria1:=noreallywhen
End With


End Sub
```

This macro takes place on "Sheet1", where there are several options by which to sort a log (on the next sheet). All other methods of sorting with the below code works great, it's just when I ask it to look for a date that it gives me 0 results, even though I know for a fact that the date I have entered is in that column in that Log sheet.

So, "Dim When" is in whatever format the user ends up typing in there. I know I've suggested a format, but who knows how they'll type it in, right? Cell D16 is formatted with the correct date format that matches the date format in the "Log" sheet. So the user types in a date, the cell next to that input takes that date and puts it in the right format, and then the macro should sort by that date. Please let me know if I'm missing something obvious??

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. This also makes sure the user inputs the date in your required format.

```
Sub Sortbydate()

With ActiveSheet
    Dim When As String
    Dim noreallywhen As String

    Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; MM-DD-YY", , Format(VBA.Now, "MM-DD-YY"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        inputstr = Split(inputbx, "-")
        On Error Resume Next
        InputDate = DateSerial(inputstr(2), inputstr(0), inputstr(1))
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(InputDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid

    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        Worksheets("Log").Columns("D:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr(InputDate)
    Else
        Worksheets("Log").Columns("D:D").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr(InputDate)
    End If

End With

Worksheets("Log").Activate

End Sub
```